# How to store list of strings to Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of strings like this:

```dart
List<String> groupIds = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'];
```

I want to store it in a Firestore document. Tried to do it via `FieldValue.arrayUnion()` but it results in `null` being stored in document.

```dart
documentReference.update({
  'groupsId': FieldValue.arrayUnion(groupIds),
})
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you just use `'groupsId': groupIds`

Comment: @towhid That results in `null` too.

Comment: that's not possible. check if you are referencing the correct node.

Comment: try to set other primitive values there to verify everything is OK

Comment: @towhid reference node is correct, tried adding a single string and it worked.

Comment: @towhid `'groupsId': groupIds` does work. Turns out I wasn't getting any actual value in `groupIds`. `a1, b1, c1` in question was just a placeholder.

Comment: should i post it as an answer?

Comment: @towhid yes please, so we can upvote it!

Comment: If you dont do it, I will proceed to post it as community wiki, so other community members can easily identify the solution.

Comment: @towhid Please post as an answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use:

```
 'groupsId': groupIds
```

here:

```
documentReference.update({
   'groupsId': groupIds
})
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: sorry, comment with json was misleading, you already have this by stating the field in update. However, I guess, you need to update element by element and not with an array as argument for the update.

documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Comment: Couldn't find the relevant part on the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data). Can you post a working example?

Comment: The given link mentions `arrayUnion` which I am already using but getting `null`. Doing it element by element would mean calling Firebase multiple times. I don't think this is feasible as there could be hundreds of ids.

Comment: you can always read a document, make changes and update the document by overwriting, also explained in the doc. Personally, I have only added single values to a Firestore array, so far